# How to remove recently added tables from mysql database

Tags: mysql, magento, xampp

Recently I have dumped some data from a magento theme into mysql, I want to undump or remove that from mysql database and want to restore the previous database.

Comment: Is the dumped data only in new tables created as part of the dump?

Comment: @Bohemian I am new to magento, was trying to dump some theme data in to mysql, so absolutely not sure :(

Comment: theme data are not dumped into the database - normally. So what did you do!? :-)

Comment: @Fabian: I got some dump.sql.gz file in a theme's sample_data, i copied media to media folder and dumped dump.sql.gz into database

Comment: how much is that? can you post it here or on pastebin?

Comment: I would examine the dump script and manually figure out what to undo/reverse. Unless you have a full backup, there's no easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the tables used in dump.sql after unzipping the archive file. drop the tables that were created while installing the theme.

To check which tables were created, check create table statement in your dump.sql. After that delete data from other tables which were not created by your theme.

Make sure you don't delete the entire table, use proper where clauses. If you need any more assistance, please post your dump.sql.

PS: Though I am not too sure if SO would allow large portion of code, though try it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help!